# How can I make traits from two different libraries compatible?

Tags: rust

I have two very similar traits from two different libraries, lets call them trait `libA::Field` and `libB::Field`. Both trait requires a significant number of other traits, both trivially derivable, like `Eq`, `Debug`, `Ord`, etc, but also many non derivable ones, like `Add`, `MulAssign`, etc.

I need to use a few types implementing `libA::Field` as `libB::Field`. This is what I tried so far:

First attempt gives error [E0210](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0210):

```rs
impl<F: libA::Field> libB::Field for F {}
```

Using an indirection also gives [E0210](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0210):

```rs
trait FieldAdaptor: libA::Field {}

impl<F: FieldAdaptor> libB::Field for F {}
```

Trying to implement the trait for the specific type also doesn't work, I get error [E0117](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0117):

```rs
impl libB::Field for libA::SomeConcreteField {}
```

Trying to wrap the `libA` types inside my own type seems to work, but I'll have to reimplement a ton of trait dependencies errors [E0277](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0277):

```rs
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
struct FieldWrapper<T>(T);

impl<T: libA::Field> libB::Field for FieldWrapper<T> {}
```

In this last attempt, the silly thing is that pretty much every trait required by `libB::Field` is already implemented by `T`, as it is already required by `libA::Field`.

Is there a generic way to use types implementing `libA::Field` as `libB::Field` without having to reimplement all traits required by `libB::Field`?

Comment: Why does using a wrapper triggers E0277?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman because `libB::Field` requires many traits already implemented by `T` as a `libA::Field`, but not implemented by `FieldWrapper<T>`.

Comment: I think your fundamental problem is that you're trying to work around the orphan rule. There are very good reasons that the orphan rule exists and is the way it is. I'd suggest re-thinking your design and perhaps asking a different question which explains why you feel the need to do this and what it might be better to do instead?

Comment: That said, I think something along the lines of your last attempt could work in principle. Define `FieldWrapper<T: libA::Field>` (derive all required derivable traits), then `impl<T> libA::Field for FieldWrapper<T>` which just passes all methods to the inner. Then `impl<T> libB::Field for FieldWrapper<T>`. Now you have a type that implements both traits. However, this still feels like a smelly design to me.

Comment: Take a look at the [`derive_more`](https://crates.io/crates/derive_more) crate. It should help you implement your wrapper type.